# preg_match_all proper syntax

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
>   [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

I have a current line of code as part of a image download script that looks like this:

```
preg_match_all('|<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i', $content, $matches);
```

I need to alter this to include:

```
id="iwi"
```

within the preg_match_all command. The img is always in this format:

I've tried a few different variations and am getting errors and finally tried without the quotes like below and still nothing, is my syntax wrong?

```
preg_match_all('|<img.*?id=iwi.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: If you don't know regex, there are [easier ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php), like `qp($html)->find("img#iwi")->attr("src")`.

Comment: Is the `id` attribute before the `src` attribute? How did you try adding quotes? Also, if you need to extract a lot of attributes like this, do yourself a favour and use an HTML parser.

Comment: I need to keep this code in place and alter it only.  The image is always in this format:  <img id="iwi" src="http://realestatesite.org/759393.jpg" alt="">

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: And how did you try it with the quotes? (And is the semicolon really there?)

Comment: Like this: preg_match_all('|<img.*?"id=iwi".*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i', $content, $matches);

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco: The quotes are in the wrong place. They should be around `iwi`, not `id=iwi`. `preg_match_all('|<img.*?id="iwi".*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i', $content, $matches);`

Comment: Well, it's a good thing that attributes in XML tags always have to be in a given, fixed order. Oh, wait....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using preg's despite all opposing-views, these methods also work;

```
// [\'"]* is useful cos sometime can't find " or ', and * means 0 or 1 time search
preg_match_all('~<img.*?id=[\'"]*([^\s\'"]*).*?src=[\'"]*([^\s\'"]*).*?>~i', $content, $matches);
preg_match_all('~<img.*?id=[\'"]*(?P<id>[^\s\'"]*).*?src=[\'"]*(?P<src>[^\s\'"]*).*?>~i', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the number one problem with [The Pony He Comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You don't know if it wil be `<img id="iwi" src="image.png" />`, or `<img src="image.png" id="iwi" />`.

Instead, you should use a parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$img = $dom->getElementById("iwi");
$src = $img->getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: Answering a duplicate question is not a valid reason to downvote a correct answer.

Comment: Oddly, I had a correct answer downvoted twice yesterday, and it eventually got 4 up votes, so it only says +2, but I got 36 rep.